# What is the cause of "version handshake timeout"?

Tags: network

This keeps happening over and over and results in me disconnecting from peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re connecting to peers that aren’t responding to you in a sensible time period so you disconnect them and try somewhere else. This isn’t really indicative of anything other than some nodes not being particularly useful to connect to.

Comment: Could this problem be on my end somehow?